# Running docker-compose command in Java application

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, zsh, processbuilder

I'm trying to run

```
docker-compose up -d
```

in Java application. Here's my code:

```
List<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();
commands.add("zsh");
commands.add("-c");
commands.add("docker-compose up --build");
Process dockerComposeCommand;
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
pb.command(commands);
pb.directory(new File(server_config.getDOCKERFILE_PATH()));
String path = System.getenv("PATH");
pb.environment().put("PATH","/usr/bin:"+path);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
pb.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);

List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    dockerComposeCommand = pb.start();
    dockerComposeCommand.waitFor();
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dockerComposeCommand.getInputStream()))) {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            result.add(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, the result was

```
zsh:1: command not found: docker-compose
```

I've checked my .zshrc file and add

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
```

to include docker-compose's path.

Did I miss something or docker-compose just can't simply execute by Java?

Any advice would be helpful!

Comment: `zsh` is not running in "interactive" mode. Add the `-i` flag. Or, use `/usr/bin/env` instead of `zsh`. I'm not sure why you want to start a new shell to then run `docker-compose`.

Comment: When you're running this, `$PATH` has only two elements, `/usr/bin` and the directory containing the Compose file.  I'd remove the part of your code that sets that environment variable (it's probably not necessary), and also remove the `sh -c` wrapper (it's unnecessary, as you've written it it adds a dependency on a non-standard shell, and for more complex commands it can introduce major security issues).

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks a lot! Problem solved by adding /usr/local/bin to $PATH!